# Debian jessie. nouveau, MMIO read fault at.... but. Any work around?

Tags: debian, drivers

I keep getting this message.

> kernel: [   25.058888] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x002140 [ !ENGINE ]

This is the var/log/messages.

> Feb 13 21:00:21 A55VD kernel: [  217.029376] ACPI Warning: _SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], AC
>   PI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)

and this is from /var/log/kern

> Feb 13 20:57:09 A55VD kernel: [   25.038145] ACPI Warning: _SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], AC
>   PI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
>   Feb 13 20:57:09 A55VD kernel: [   25.058888] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x002140 [ !ENGINE ]

I'm guessing that this ACPI warning is causing something to happen with the nouveau driver but that is just my guess.  So my question is what can I do about this, it's getting really annoying.  I'm noticing that when I am using a graphic intensive program, mostly this is happening with krita, after a while it hangs sometimes the computer freezes and if I can get to tty1 I can sometimes killall and that works, slowly.  Other times I've had to poweroff manually.  I'm guessing because I have no idea what I'm doing.

I'm downloading the Nvidia drivers for geforce 610M and going to see if that works?  Will using the Nvidia drivers work and or resolve the issue?

ps.  sorry for the long post to ask if a different driver will work.